# Call member function of a class in boost thread

Tags: multithreading, boost, shared-ptr

I have the following two functions, the first one crashes but the second one runs fine.
I understand that for the first one, object is destroyed when run() returns, but the thread is still executing its work() function, which can lead to undefined behaviours.

But why does the second one work? If we we wrap the object in a shared_ptr, it will outlive the thread?

Please enlighten me. Thanks.

```
void run() {
    Object object();
    boost::thread t(&Object::work, &object);
}

void run() {
    std::shared_ptr<Object> object_(new Object());
    boost::thread t(&Object::work, object);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Bind stores parameters by value.

This implies a copy of the shared pointer is around until the bind expression goes out of existence. This keeps the Object around.

Interesting note: `boost::bind` supports binding to `shared_ptr<T>` for the `this` parameter of a member function. `std::bind` doesn't have this feature (yet?)

Comment: where is the bind expression? t(&Object::work, &object) is calling bind implicitly?

Comment: @jiawen Yes. Sorry, that could have been clearer. In fact, it's not required to use `boost::bind`, but `std::thread` construction `std::bind` are specified in the same way. This also implies that if you want to bind references, you need `boost::ref(object)` (or `std::ref(object)`)